# How do i know in certain place in code, that it is invoked by Cron service?

Tags: java, spring, cron

In my code i have method that i would like to behave differently if it is invoked by my Cron Scheduler service. How can I achieve this?

Comment: In your crontab, specify an argument to the method.

Answer (score 0):

In Highlevel you can do like this, From crontab invoke the script - `example.sh`

From the `example.sh` file invoke the jsp page using wget, which invokes a java class.

```
wget --quiet -O ${APPLICATION_PATH}/jspName.jsp?parameterOne=${parameterOne}
```

In your java class use - `request.getParameter("parameterOne");`
Based on this parameter write the logic.

Comment: I believe I fixed a few typoes: Please check/update as necessary. I removed an extra `)` and fixed the typo in `example.sh`.